# Override Hydra config with experiment config- extra folder hierarchy

Tags: python, configuration, fb-hydra

I'm working through this [Hydra doc example](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/) to override the main config with an experiment config. Differing from the Hydra example I have another level of folder hierarchy to gather all associated configs into a single sub-folder.

```
conf
├── data
│   ├── cifar100_data
│   │   ├── cifar100_extended.yaml
│   │   └── cifar100.yaml
│   └── default.yaml
├── experiment
│   └── cifar100.yaml
└── training_config.yaml
```

In my example, I have a basic `training_config`:

```
defaults:
   - data: default
```

`data/default.yaml`:

```
# @package data
dataset: mnist
n_classes: 10
```

and two config files for cifar100 data
`cifar100_data/cifar100.yaml`:

```
name: cifar100
n_classes: 100
```

`cifar100_data/cifar100_extended.yaml`:

```
# @package data
defaults:
  - cifar100
augmentations:
  - rotate
```

I'm trying to override `training_config` with `experiment/cifar100` --> `python my_app.py experiment=cifar100`:

`experiment/cifar100` try 1:

```
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - override /data/cifar100_data: cifar100_extended
```

error message:

> hydra.errors.ConfigCompositionException: In 'experiment/cifar100':
> Could not override 'data/cifar100_data'. No match in the defaults
> list.

`experiment/cifar100` try 2:

```
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - override /data: cifar100_data/cifar100_extended
```

error message:

> hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: In
> 'data/cifar100_data/cifar100_extended': Could not load
> 'data/cifar100'.

How can I properly run such an experiment with an extra hierarchy compared to default config?

**EDIT following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78158494/6293886)**:
I've adjust `cifar100_extended.yaml` to:

```
# @package data
defaults:
  - cifar100_data/cifar100
augmentations:
  - rotate
```

as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78158494/6293886), and was able to generate a valid config.
However, now I can't run `cifar100_extended.yaml` directly, and recieving the following error

```
hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: In 'cifar100_data/cifar100_extended': Could not load 'cifar100_data/cifar100_data/cifar100'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This a bit unusual. Your data config group should be `data`, not `/data/cifar100_data`, so the second form is the correct one:

```yaml
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - override /data: cifar100_data/cifar100_extended
```

The error you are getting is:

```
hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: In 'data/cifar100_data/cifar100_extended': Could not load 'data/cifar100'.
```

This is telling you that while trying to data/cifar100_data/cifar100_extended, Hydra attempted to load data/cifar100 and could not find it.
Indeed, that file is in `data/cifar100_data/cifar100` and not in `data/cifar100`.

This looks like a bug because relative config group entries should be relative to the containing config, and cifa100 is right next to cifar100_extended.

The bug is related to your unusual construction of a config group with sub directories which is not something that is properly supported (normally the expectation is that each sub directory is its own config group).

A work around is to adjust `cifar100_extended.yaml` to:

```
# @package data
defaults:
  - cifar100_data/cifar100
augmentations:
  - rotate
```

Comment: thanks, this solution is working. however that way an extra level was added  in the final config (`data.cifar100_data`) I'd prefer it to be a direct descendant of `data`. The reason for this sub-directories is to make to code base neater and more organized. If one have multiple datasources each of them compose of multiple files it's make sense to distribute them in seperate folders

Comment: `cifar100_data/cifar100@_here_` solve the above issue

Comment: I've edited the question, now I can't run `cifar100_extended`  alone

Comment: As I said, this is a bug. Unfortunately, the workaround is just that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your original config working by removing the `override` keyword from the `conf/experiment/cifar100.yaml` file:

```yaml
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - /data/cifar100_data: cifar100_extended
```

```yaml
$ python test.py +experiment=cifar100
data:
  dataset: mnist
  n_classes: 100
  name: cifar100
  augmentations:
  - rotate
```

I'm not sure if this is your desired output, however. Did you want the cifar configuration to be nested under the `data.cifar100_data` package? If so, you can use the [`group@pkg`](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/#default-list-package-keywords) syntax within your `conf/experiment/cifar100.yaml` file:

```yaml
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - /data/cifar100_data@data.cifar100_data: cifar100_extended
```

```yaml
$ python test.py +experiment=cifar100
data:
  dataset: mnist
  n_classes: 10
  cifar100_data:
    name: cifar100
    n_classes: 100
    augmentations:
    - rotate
```

The `override` keyword is useful you're overriding something that already appears elsewhere in your defaults tree. In this case, the experiment file is not overriding `data/cifar100_data`, which does not appear elsewhere in the defaults tree.